# MySQL cascade hard delete child row on soft delete of parent row without using a trigger: is this possible?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.47-87.0

I have a parent table named `parentTable` and a child table named `childTable`, here's the scripts to create those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `parentTable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=251046 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `childTable` (
  `parentId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text
  PRIMARY KEY (`parentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `childtable_parentid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `parentTable` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As is the child record in `childTable` is hard deleted when the corresponding record in the `parentTable` is hard deleted.

Without using a trigger, is it possible to set this up so the record in `childTable` is hard deleted when the corresponding record in `parentTable` is soft deleted (IE: when the `parentTable.deleted` column is updated with a value so is it no longer `NULL`)?

Comment: I don't think so. MySQL doesn't know anything about soft deletion, that's at the application level.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking that was the case, but posted this question in the hope someone would know of a way. Thanks!